# getting the grand total and email using order id in magento

Tags: php, magento

In my redirect file, I'm trying to get the grand total of a customer's cart and also email using the order id but on redirecting to the bank payment gateway which I'm using, it retruns a response that the amount sent is invalid. Which simply means, I'm sending an empty parameter.

The form field name is "amt" while the form field for email is "email"

Below is the code:

```
<?php
// Retrieve order
$_order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$_order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="amt" value="<?php echo $_order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="<?php echo $orderId; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail() ; ?>">
</form>
```

Can anyone help out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be able to find the last order.  Try

```
<?php $_order = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrder(); ?>
<?php if (!$_order || !$_order->getId()): ?>
<!-- no last order found -->
<?php else: ?>
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="amt" value="<?php echo $_order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_order->getCustomerEmail(); ?>">
</form>
<?php endif ?>
```